# ASP.NET buttons not firing onclick events every time they are clicked

Tags: asp.net

I have a visual studio 2013 express for the web application with forms and controls. My buttons are not firing the onclick events every time they are clicked. Does anyone know what I can try to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: What button type are you using? What click event are you using? Are you referring to client-side or server-side click events?

Comment: Show us the code what you are tried.